# How to Hide a ModalPopupExenter that has a User Control from another page?

Tags: c#

I have a User Control called: Share.ascx

I have a page called: News.aspx

In News.aspx I created a ModalPopupExtender, then I addeda  Panel and inside the Panel I added the User Control: Share.ascx so that when the Popup Extender is called the Panel with the User Control is displayed.

The problem:

I can only HIDE the ModalPopupExtender from News.aspx because ModalPopupExtender is defined there but I need to call the HIDE funciton of ModalPopupExtender from the User Control: Share.ascx.cs

How do I do that?

Thank you.

----------------------News.aspx-------------------------

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server">

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnShare" runat="server" Text='Share Link' /> 

    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"  
    TargetControlID="lbtnShare" PopupControlID="Panel1" 
    Drag="true" RepositionMode=RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:panel id="Panel1" runat="server" style="display:none">
        <uc2:ShareLink ID="ShareLink" runat="server" />
    </asp:panel>
</asp:Content>
```

----------------------Share.ascx-------------------------

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSET" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

The files are too long so I omitted a lot of it and only put the important parts.

Share.ascx has a Cancel button, in that button I want to call the Hide() function of ModalPopupExtender1 that is located in News.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the usercontrol code behind try to find your ModalPopupExtender

```
var popup = Parent.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1") as ModalPopupExtender;
```

and then call the Hide() method

```
popup.Hide();
```

Comment: But the modal popup is in the News.aspx page not in the user control.

Comment: Didn't try the solution but think it will work because when you add Share.ascx to the News.aspx page it become a part of this page and FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1") will work. this solution supose that you don't have a masterpage, if you have a masterpage you have to navigate to them modalpopupextender with something like this.Master.FindControl("MessageContent").FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1") as ModalPopupExtender

Comment: var popup = FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1") as ModalPopupExtender;
Didn't work, it returns null which means it didn't find the ModalPopup extender. Is there any way to do this using Event handlers between pages, if so can you give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you man, your edited solution: var popup = Parent.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1") as ModalPopupExtender; worked perfectly. +Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the Ok and cancel controls from the parent form in your ModalPopupExtender by appending the ID of your Cancel button to the ID of the User Control. I use the following code:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
            TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="UpdatePanel1"
            OkControlID="OpenRec1_btnOK"
            CancelControlID="OpenRec1_btnCancel">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:OpenRec runat="server" id="OpenRec1" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The Ok and Cancel buttons in my User Control are named btnOK and btnCancel.